# AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm' (discord.py, I'm trying to dm all members of a guild)

Tags: python, discord.py, send, dm

I've been trying to send a DM to all members of a guild, but I always get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'
```

This is my code

```py
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *, message):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        channel = await member.create_dm()
        channel.send(message)
    await ctx.send('Messages successfully sent!')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I have to await the channel.send